# removing all nodes of a type within a GridPane

Tags: java, groovy, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to build a checkers game and I'm currently trying to implement the moving of the pieces.
To do this I decided I'd keep a list of where the pieces should be:
`blackPieces`
`whitePieces`

Then when a movement is made I would:

1. update the relevant list
2. loop through all the children of the GridPane
3. remove all the checkers pieces i.e. all Nodes of type Circle
4. add new pieces according to relevant list

However, I'm stuck at step 3, with the following Groovy code I simply get a **ConcurrentModificationException**

```
def children = board.getChildren()
for (child in children) {
    if (child instanceof Circle) {
        board.getChildren().remove(child)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this without redrawing the entire scene?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: You need a Iterator for removing while looping.

Comment: In Java you can do `board.getChildren().removeIf(Circle.class::isInstance);`.  I'm not sure if there is an equivalent construct in Groovy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is even an easier way, thanks to groovy's [removeAll](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) method that takes a closure.

```
board.getChildren().removeAll{ it instanceof Circle }
```

Answer (score 1):

[You shouldn't use `instanceof`](https://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/when-polymorphism-fails). What you should do is program against an interface, isntead of against an implementation. By this I mean have all of the black and white piece implement an interface, maybe `Piece`. Then have your GridPane populated by classes that implement `Piece`. In your `Piece` interface you could have a method, maybe `isCircle()` that does the obvious check. Now you can use your solution, but using the `isCircle()` method.

Comment: That won't work of course, because the other nodes in the `GridPane`'s list of children don't have a `isCircle()` method. If you want to avoid `instanceof`, you should probably store the pieces in a separate data structure. Following that, you pretty quickly get to the point of implementing a separate model class and following a MVC/MVP approach.

Comment: That's why I suggested having all the nodes in the `GridPane` implement a `Piece` interface and let `Piece` have the isCircle() method. But you're right, the MVC/MVP and the separate data structure is probably better design.

Comment: I don't see how that works, but maybe I am missing something. Provide a quick implementation if you have time. It doesn't solve the original problem, of course, `for (child in children) { if (child.isCircle()) { children.remove(child);} } ` still throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`, but you knew that already, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Wow so randomly browsing Groovy cheat sheets and Collection methods I put together this solution.

```
def pieces = board.getChildren().findAll { it instanceof Circle } // gets all the pieces
board.getChildren().removeAll(pieces) // removes them
```

win.